# 4K UHDTV HDMI half screen flicker and flash on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I've searched and tried almost all the fixes available on Google.

Setup:
Model: HP-Pavillion ab032tx
CPU: Intel Core i5
RAM: 16 GB DDR3
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 64-Bit
Kernel: 4.8.0-56-generic
Graphics Cards: Intel Onboard HD Graphics(i915) and nvida 940M(nvidia-375) on Optimus

Bumblebee configured and nvidia is selected as primary.

Issue:
I've configured my laptop to use only external display by turning off the inbuilt in settings.
External display is my Vizio 4K UHD TV connected via HDMI.

As soon as I boot up after a minute or so, precisely only half portion of the screen starts flashing or flickers.

https://youtu.be/cWPS5s1WOM8

Once in a while the whole screen goes blank for a second and comes back on.

https://youtu.be/RF9v6qdPFCc

This happens with inbuilt nouveau drivers and Intel i915 as primary as well.

Please help.. _/|_